# In Star Trek TOS, does someone say textually "It's life, but not as we know it"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, quotes

There are a few quotes from Star Trek that aren't actually ever said (such as "Beam me up, Scotty"). Is there an actual episode where Spock (or even McCoy) says something akin to

> It's life, but not as we know it.

Comment: Star trekkin, across the universe, on the Starship Enterprise, under Captain Kirk!  The Firm!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trekkin%27

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the places that "quotes" it, most notably.

Comment: The TV Tropes page for "Beam me up, Scotty!" has several Star Trek examples, including this one: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeamMeUpScotty

Comment: Its worse than that he's dead Jim, dead Jim, dead Jim, Its worse than that he's dead Jim, dead Jim, dead!

Comment: Ya canna change the laws of physics, laws of physics, laws of physics, ya canna change the laws of physics, laws of physics Captain.

Comment: There's Klingons on the starboard bow, starboard bow, starboard bow, there's Klingons on the starboard bow, starboard bow, Captain.

Comment: I love that song!  :)

Comment: Oh damn, ear worm'd.

Comment: As an aside, the actual beam me up quotes are Kirk saying, "Beam me up, Mister Spock." (Squire of Gothos) And, "This is the Captain. Beam me up." (This Side of Paradise.)

Comment: Ah! We come in peace, shoot to kill, shoot to kill, shoot to kill...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looking through [this site](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/episodes.htm) which has transcripts of all Star Trek episodes the line does not appear. There are a couple of lines that come close though:

From season 1 episode 26, The Devil In The Dark:

> SPOCK: Within range of our sensors, there is no life, other than the accountable human residents of this colony beneath the surface. At least, no life as we know it.

And later in the same episode:

> SPOCK: Life as we know it is universally based on some combination of carbon compounds, but what if life exists based on another element? For instance, silicon.

From season 1 episode 29, Operation: Annihilate!:

> SPOCK: It is not life as we know or understand it. Yet it is obviously alive, it exists.

Answer (score 10):

In "Errand of Mercy" from TOS (S1E26), after the Organians reveal their true nature as beings of pure energy and literally stop both the Federation and Klingon fleets dead in space, Spock says something to the effect of: "Not life as we know it at all".

Comment: "Fascinating. Pure energy. Pure thought. Totally incorporeal. Not life as we know it at all." http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/27.htm

Answer (score -6):

It doesn't figure because the phrase didn't come from Star Trek!  It's actually from the contemporaneous movie, "Thunderbirds Are Go!"

Comment: Can you provide a context with this quote? From the film?

Comment: Not quite: [“I have a feeling that we may encounter life as we don’t know it.”](http://thunderbirds.wikia.com/wiki/Thunderbirds_Are_Go_(film)/Transcript)

Comment: The phrase having been said in one series does not make it impossible to have been said in another.